# Add Scribus reference to Visual Studio 2019 Python project

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019, scribus

I would like to make some Scribus scripts. Normally I use Visual Studio 2019 for other tasks, so I am wondering, is it possible to add somehow Scribus to references?
Now I see `unresolved import 'scribus'` in my scripts and there's not intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, there is still no official way to debug scribus scripter in Visual Studio or any other program.

However, because I was very annoyed by this, I spent way too much time makin a [scribus dummy script](https://github.com/Tre5et/scribus-dummy) that currently includes all the scripter functions.

Hope this helps someone trying to do this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your scripts with Visual Studio, but you will need to run them from inside of Scribus:

- You write your Script in VS
- Keep an open Scribus instance
- Save your changes
- Run your script from the Scribus menus

In the past, when creating scripts that would have little interaction with Scribus documents but lot of *calculations*, I've created a [MockAPI](https://github.com/aoloe/scribus-script-repository/tree/master/mockAPI) that was replicating a few Scribus commands.

One day we will be able to use Scribus *as a library* but there is lot of work to be done to get there...

Comment: Thanks, this also says that there's no built-in way to actually use the Scribus itself?

Comment: Built-in in Visual Studio? Built-in in python? Both do not exist, no. Debugging is an issue, but otherwise, it's not that uncomfortable.